# is there any way to convert vaadin CallbackDataProvider<Object, Void> to ListDataProvider<Object>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am using `CallbackDataProvider<Object, Void> dataprovider` and then setting `dataprovider` in `grid` using `grid.setDataProvider`.
Then in `TextField` `addValueChangeListener` method I am trying to call `grid.getDataProvider()` which is returning me `CallbackDataProvider` instance.
After that, I am trying to cast in `ListDataProvider` for filtering in which I am getting `ClassCastException` But when I am using `PaginatedGrid` `getDataProvider` is returning `ListDataProvider` instance.
Here I don't want to use `PaginatedGrid`, is there any way to convert `CallBackDataProvider` to `ListDataProvider` using `Grid`?

Comment: You are combining in-memory data with lazy fetching. Look at https://vaadin.com/docs/v21/flow/binding-data/data-provider/#assigning-a-list-or-array-of-in-memory-data and the following paragraphs to get the idea how to filter data when lazy fecthing (CallbackDataProvider) or how to use in-memory data (ListDatProvider).

Answer (score 3):

To answer your literal question, no, you can not convert a CallbackDataProvider to a ListDataProvider. Your underlying problem is stated between the lines here:

> I am trying to cast in ListDataProvider for filtering

So your problem is that you want to filter the data, but the CallbackDataProvider doesn't provide a similar method for it as a ListDataProvider. There is a reason for this - ListDataProvider stores all of its items in memory inside a Java Collection, so it's straightforward to filter the backing Collection. A CallbackDataProvider is lazy-loading and doesn't know *where* the full set of items is, so you need to implement the filtering yourself against the backing data source.

To filter a lazy loading DataProvider, you'll need a ConfigurableFilterDataProvider. First, instead of creating your CallbackDataProvider with `DataProvider.fromCallbacks`, you need to use `DataProvider.fromFilteringCallbacks`. This enables you to use the `filter` of the `query` object and you can implement the filtering of your backend data as you see fit. Second, you'll need to wrap your DataProvider into a ConfigurableFilterDataProvider with `dataProvider.withConfigurableFilter` so that you can pass a filter object of your choosing.

You can find a full example here: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider/#filtering-based-on-another-component